# Чи правильно вживати в українській мові слово "поняв" в значенні "зрозумів"?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, етимологія, словотворення

Слово "поняв" лаконічне і в народі кругом використовується. Але з однієї сторони здається, що це калька з російського слова 'понял'. А з іншої сторони в словнику Сум бачу, що воно використовується в значенні 'піймав'. http://sum.in.ua/s/pojnjaty

Але якщо взяти ту ж англійську, то там також в розмовній мові використовуєть 'got it' - в значенні зрозумів, а не прямий переклад - піймав.

Отже думаю варто роз'яснити цю ситуацію :)

Comment: Ще можна вжити зрозуміло, мені втямки або затямив.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тим часом згаданий вами словник — СУМ-11 — має також:

> [**ПОНЯ́ТТЯ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/ponjattja), я, *сер*.
>
> 1. Одна із форм мислення, результат узагальнення суттєвих ознак обʼєкта дійсності.
> 2. Розуміння кимсь чого-небудь, що склалося на основі якихось відомостей, власного досвіду.
>
>    //  Думка про що-небудь, погляд на щось.
>
>    //  *тільки мн.* Сукупність поглядів на що-небудь, рівень розуміння чогось.
>
>    **Не мати [жодного, найменшого] поняття** — не мати уявлення про що-небудь, не бути обізнаним з чимсь, не знати чого-небудь.

Але, так, слово має корінь:

> [**Я́ТИ**](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F#26737) — «взятися, почати»
>
> - дещо віддаленішими, але також пов’язаними з попередніми, є відповідники інших індоєвропейських мов, пор. лтс. [jem̃t], ņemt «брати», дінд. yámati «тримає», тох. А yom-, тох. В yäm- «досягати», гр. νέμω «розподіляю», гот. niman «брати», н. nehmen «тс.»;
> - споріднене з лит. im̃ti «брати», прус. īmt «тс.», лат. ēmō «купую», ст. «приймаю», умбр. emantur «приймаються», оск. (pert)emest «відіймає», дірл. (air-fo-)emim «хапаю»;
> - псл. (j)ęti, (j)ьmǫ (1 ос. одн.) продовжує іє. *em-;

Де посеред прикладів також можна побачити:

> 162. по́єм «поняття»
>
> 168. понима́ти «осягати (розумом), розуміти, схоплювати»
> 169. понимли́вий «тямущий, тямкий»
>
> 178. поня́тний «зрозумілий; ясний, чіткий»
>
> 251. я́тва «розуміння»

Справді цікавий збіг з  *get it*. Сюди також можна згадати подібне [*catch on*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catch_on#English) — і українське *вловити*.

Але такого також мають декілька словянських мов.

> [**pojęcie**](https://wsjp.pl/haslo/do_druku/70045/pojecie)
>
> Pochodzenie: Zob. *jąć*
>
> 1. *matematyczne* to, co istnieje w myślach człowieka i jest odzwierciedleniem tego, jak człowiek postrzega świat, i czemu niekiedy nadaje się odrębną nazwę
> 2. *o życiu* to, co ktoś wie lub myśli na dany temat, rozumiejąc coś lub wyobrażając sobie coś w określony sposób

Є відповідне дієслово:

> [**pojąć**](https://wsjp.pl/haslo/do_druku/33086/pojac)
>
> 1. *treść*, *książk.* poznać sens, istotę lub przebieg czegoś
>
>    synonimy: *obczaić, pokumać, sczaić, skapować, skumać, zakapować, zakumać, zrozumieć*
> 2. *w jakiś sposób*, *książk.*  przypisać czemuś określone znaczenie
>
>    synonimy: *zrozumieć*
> 3. *kogoś*, *książk*. wczuć się w czyjeś przeżycia, pragnienia i poznać motywy postępowania
>
>    synonimy: *zrozumieć*

Про всяк знайма етімолоґія корня:

> [**jąć**](https://wsjp.pl/haslo/podglad/28448/jac)
>
> Pochodzenie: psł. *(j)ęti, *(j)ьmǫ 'wziąć, chwycić rękami, schwytać, złapać, ująć; zacząć, rozpocząć'

На цьому можна було би спинити ся, але [Виталь Моргунюк](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk733/TK_wisnyk733_1_morhun%27uk.htm) так не думає, бо думає, що це також польський вплив через (увага) старішої роботи Василя Сімовича — 1924 року.

Дуже примітивний підхід: якщо немає в мойому реґіоні чи в словниці Грінченка, тоді такого слова немає. Словники, особливо тих часів, не могли покривати всі слова чи тлуми, але зараз маємо, чого не було або були дуже слабкими в 2012, корпуси, котрі можуть допомогти. І видно, що *поняття* в часи Грінченка було поширеним словом, потрапило в словник [Кримського](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on), а щонадавніший вжиток — 1891. А *понимати* в сенсі *розуміти* — щонадавніше 1865 від Миколи Устияновича, що був під Австро-Угорщиною. Про всяк зазначу, що письмова мова зазвичай пізніша за розмовну.

А також наведу ще одну мову, котра чомусь не була згадана — а шкода, поглянув би на доводи — в його статті, далеку від нас, польської і москівської, але досі словянської — [південословянську](https://hjp.znanje.hr):

> **pojam**
>
> 2. *razg.*
>
>    - osnovno znanje o čemu
>    - mišljenje o komu ili čemu; predodžba
>
> // **nemati pojma** ne znati ništa o čemu;
>
> Etimologija: vidi *pòimati*

> **pòimati**
>
> 2. razumijevati na razini pojmova
>
> Etimologija: po- + v. *imati*

І знов доходимо до знаймої етімолоґії корня:

> **ìmati**
>
> *prasl*. *iměti 〈prez. *imamь〉 (*rus*. imét', iméju, *polj*. mieć, mam) ≃ *prasl*. *jęti: uzeti, *lit*. imti ← *ie*. *h<sub>1</sub>em- (*lat*. emere: kupiti)

Тож, підсумок простий: правильно вживати *поняти* як *зрозуміти*. Для цього є підстави як однокороневі слова з подібним смислом, а також словники. Приклади з гинших словянських мов лише підкреслюють, що то не калька з москівської, ба навіть сусідних мов. Але варто памятати, що і самі зазначили — слово розмовне, тобто в діловій мові уникайте.